# Recover Files From GUIless Ubuntu

Tags: grub2, data-recovery

I've installed my computer Ubuntu 12.04 and i've customized a bit.

I've disable gui via editing /etc/default/grub

```
Change 

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash”

to

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”text”

and then

sudo update-grub
```

I've disabled password login via editingh /etc/init/tty1.conf

```
exec /bin/login -f USERNAME < /dev/tty1 > /dev/tty1 2>&1
```

Finally i add my program to start up via;

```
sudo mv /filename /etc/init.d/
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/filename 
sudo update-rc.d filename defaults
```

But when computer boots up, can't see anything on the monitor. When i tried to push power button, my programs default greeting message appear on the screen with no keyboard function. My program runs throuhg infinite loop so can't stop by itself.

I want to stop this program and recover files from this machine but, no keyboard function limits my operations.

PS: I can't remember whether i installed the ssh or not. Disabling startup program will work fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to [start Ubuntu in recovery mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode) (akin to "Safe Mode" of Windows). Then do what you want — modify the configuration files back to the defaults and/or recover your files. Alternatively, if that doesn't work, you can start the Live CD instead of starting Ubuntu in recovery mode.

Comment: @eiki That's odd; LiveUSB has and should be working, whether your installed Ubuntu is broken or not. I've updated the answer.